# Proving that $\sum_{i=2}^n(5i-4)=\frac{n(5n-3)-2}{2}$ for all $n\geq 1$ by mathematical induction

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, induction

I have this question:

Show, using mathematical induction, that for all natural numbers $n$,

$$6 + 11 + 16 + 21 + \cdots + (5n-4) = \frac{n(5n-3)-2}{2}$$

---

I am confused in that that question states for all $natural$ $numbers$... 
yet if you take $1$ (for example as the base case) which is a $natural$ $number$
it does not work:

LHS: $(5n-4) = (5(1)-4) = 1$

RHS:  $\frac{n(5n-3)-2}{2} = \frac{1(5(1)-3)-2}{2} = 0$

Am I understaning/doing something wrong? 
Should I just take $S(2)$ as the base step?
How would I go about solving this problem?

Comment: The problem should really say "for all natural numbers $n$ such that $n\geq 2$". You can see the left hand side sum starts from $6$ which is when $n=2$. So just take $n=2$ as the base case.

Comment: Since the first listed number is $6 = 5\cdot 2 - 4$, for $n = 1$ you have an empty sum, whose value is $0$, which is also the value of the right hand side.

Comment: Thank KittyL I see it is a problem with the way the question is written.

Comment: I'm sorry Daniel Fischer could you explain what that means a little more, I am not familiar with some of the mathematical terminology you used. What are you suggesting I do?

Comment: I think Daniel Fischer is pointing out that if you use summation notation, you would write this as $\sum_{k=2}^n (5k-4) = \frac{n(5n-3)-2)}{2}$.  That is, the left-hand-side is the sum of $5k-4$, for $k$ such that $2 \leq k \leq n$.  If $n = 1$, there are no valid $k$, so the sum is zero, and the identity succeeds.

Comment: 6+11 $\neq{\frac{2(10-3)-2}{2}}$; 6+11+16 $\neq{\frac{3(15-3)-2}{2}}$. I don't understand

Comment: I'm not convinced this doesn't work when $n=1$.  When $n=1$, then the fraction on the right is $0$, and the number of terms on the left is $0$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @LuisGomezSanchez: $6+11 = 17$ is the LHS for $n = 3$, and $\frac{3(15-3)-2}{2} = \frac{34}{2} = 17$.  You're just off by one.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: I think that is exactly Daniel Fischer's point.

Comment: @BrianTung Yes, precisely. I am trying to write up an answer now that addresses the empty sum and also makes mention of the empty product and *then* show the inductive proof. We'll see how this turns out.

Comment: I have done so also.

Comment: @Brian Tung: Please, I don't know what LHS and RHS are.

Comment: @LuisGomezSanchez : I assume those mean "left-hand side" and "right-hand side".

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments have indicated, the equation is actually valid for $n = 1$, after a fashion.  It is clearer when written as a summation:

$$
\sum_{k=2}^n (5k-4) = \frac{n(5n-3)-2}{2}
$$

Spelled out in words, the above equation reads, "The sum of $(5k-4)$, from $k = 2$ to $n$, equals $\ldots$"  When $n = 1$, the summation on the left is *empty*, and an empty sum is by definition equal to zero (which equals the fraction on the right).  For a more familiar identity, we might write

$$
\sum_{k=1}^n k = 1+2+3+\cdots+n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}
$$

When $n = 0$, the summation on the left is empty, so the sum is zero (which, again, equals the fraction on the right).  The confusing part of your question is that the summand (the $(5k-4)$ you're adding up) is not actually zero for $n = 1$, so it is easy to make the mistake of using it in the sum.  But in fact the limits of the sum dictate that it not be included.

Anyway, to prove by induction: The above will serve as the basis case.  The induction step is to assume that

$$
\sum_{k=2}^{n-1} (5k-4) = \frac{(n-1)[5(n-1)-3]-2}{2}
$$

and show that adding $5n-4$ to both sides of the equation yields

$$
\sum_{k=2}^n (5k-4) = \frac{n(5n-3)-2}{2}
$$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

What Daniel Fischer, Brian Tung, Michael Hardy, and myself now are referring to is that the [empty sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_sum) is taken to be zero; on the other hand, the [empty product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_product) is taken to be one. More concretely, 
$$
\sum_{i=r}^k\Omega_i=0\quad\text{when}\quad k<r\quad\text{and}\quad\prod_{i=r}^k\Omega_i=1\quad\text{when}\quad k<r.
$$
Now, consider Brian's comment; you are trying to prove that
$$
\sum_{i=2}^n(5i-4)=\frac{n(5n-3)-2}{2}
$$
for all natural numbers $n$ (i.e., $n\geq 1$, where $n\in\mathbb{Z}$). Let's do this, now that we have addressed the empty sum issue.

---

**Claim:** For all $n\geq 1$, where $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, we have that $\sum_{i=2}^n(5i-4)=\frac{n(5n-3)-2}{2}$.

*Proof.* For $n\geq 1$, let $S(n)$ denote the statement
$$
S(n) : \sum_{i=2}^n(5i-4)=\frac{n(5n-3)-2}{2}.
$$
**Base case ($n=1$):** $S(1)$ says that $\sum_{i=\color{purple}{2}}^\color{red}{1}(5i-4)=\underbrace{0}_{\text{since $\color{red}{1}<\color{purple}{2}$}}=\frac{(5-3)-2}{2}$, and this is true.

**Inductive step $S(k)\to S(k+1)$:** Fix some $k\geq 1$, and suppose that 
$$
S(k) : \color{blue}{\sum_{i=2}^k(5i-4)}=\color{blue}{\frac{k(5k-3)-2}{2}}
$$
holds. To be shown is that $S(k+1)$ follows where
$$
S(k+1) : \color{green}{\sum_{i=2}^{k+1}(5i-4)}=\color{green}{\frac{(k+1)(5k+2)-2}{2}}.
$$
Starting with the left-hand side of $S(k+1)$,
\begin{align}
\color{green}{\sum_{i=2}^{k+1}(5i-4)} &= \color{blue}{\sum_{i=2}^k(5i-4)}+[5(k+1)-4]\tag{by defn. of $\Sigma$}\\[0.5em]
&= \color{blue}{\frac{k(5k-3)-2}{2}}+5k+1\tag{by $S(k)$, the ind. hyp.}\\[1em]
&= \frac{5k^2-3k-2+10k+2}{2}\tag{common denom}\\[1em]
&= \frac{5k^2+7k+2-2}{2}\tag{simplify / rearrange}\\[1em]
&= \color{green}{\frac{(k+1)(5k+2)-2}{2}},\tag{factor}
\end{align}
we end up at the right-hand side of $S(k+1)$, completing the inductive step.

Thus, by mathematical induction, the statement $S(n)$ is true for all $n\geq 1$. $\blacksquare$